# Sumar horas y obtener más de 24h

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

Tengo una función en Typescript con la que sumo horas y minutos, todo se ejecuta en ngOnInit ,con la librería moment, he conseguido que esta operación me sume las horas, pero cuando pasa de 23:59 me añade un día y así un mes, pero con la fecha de 1970.

He multiplicado el número de días x 24 y las horas restantes

```
ngOnInit() {
this.getRequest.response((res: any[]) => {
        
  const total: any[] = Object.create(res).filter(it => it);
  this.totalHoras = 0;
  this.auxTotalHoras = 0;
 
  total.forEach( (tareas, index)  => {
    if( tareas.horas_totales != null ) {
      if (tareas.horas_totales.length > 0) {
          let hora_minuto = (tareas.horas_totales as string).split(":");
          this.totalHoras = moment(this.totalHoras).add(hora_minuto[0],'hours').add(hora_minuto[1],'minutes');
        }
    }

    if ( index + 1 >= total.length ){
      let meses = moment(this.totalHoras).format('MM');
      let dias = parseInt(moment(this.totalHoras).format('DD'));

      if ( dias > 1 ) {
        let horas = moment(this.totalHoras).format('HH:mm');
        this.totalHoras =   ((dias -1) * 24) + parseInt(horas[0]) + ':' + (horas[1].length == 1? '0'+ horas[1]: horas[1]);
      }  else {
        this.totalHoras = moment(this.totalHoras).format('HH:mm');
      }
    }

  });
```

});
Pero veo que esta no es la manera correcta, cuando pase a meses me contará, cada mes con sus días.
Enero 31
Febrero 28-29
Etc...
Esto producirá un descuadre a corto plazo, ya que son muchas tareas.
Siento no haberme explicado correctamente.
Agradecer las respuestas.

Comment: Creo que estas haciendo pasos extra, deberías de convertir la fecha a un objeto de tiempo, hacer el "desfase" de tiempo y luego convertir el resultado a string. Cuál es el formato que usas para las fechas?

Comment: Respondo al primer comentario. La hora llega en formato string por ejemplo 8:00, lo que hago es dividir, para asignar horas y minutos. Gracias por responder

Comment: Al segundo comentario, utilizo lo que estás viendo, disculpa no entiendo lo desfase de tiempo, puedes añadir un ejemplo por favor. Gracias por responder

Comment: @masterguru, la línea que te da error es porque se trata de Typescript. Aunque el OP no lo dice explícitamente.

Comment: masterguru, siento no haberme explicado correctamente, he reeditado la pregunta, para que sea lo más precisa posible, gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por la aclaración, ya borré mi comentario